# css not able to load font in correct way

Tags: html, css

i have to load font into css from folder, but it is not working

html

is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        @font-face { font-family: 'HelveticaWorld'; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; src: URL("../Fonts/HelveticaWorld-Bold.ttf") format('ttf'); }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
            <div style="margin-bottom: 15px; font-weight: bold;font-family: HelveticaWorld"">Setup</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**[download physical html file ( zip)](http://www8.zippyshare.com/v/99800201/file.html)**

Comment: In which browser are you testing this code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the zip file, your font path and format are wrong. Try:

```
@font-face { font-family: 'HelveticaWorld'; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; src: URL("font/HelveticaWorld-Bold.ttf") format('truetype'); }
```

Comment: Spotted the `format` was wrong too - it should be `truetype` not `ttf`

Comment: Hi, are you able to send me zip?

Comment: No need - just overwrite the `@font-face` declaration in your code with the one above.